# How to create module programmatically to show all manufacturer in front end?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, programmatically-created

As i am new in Magneto i don't know how to create a module but now I start creating module in 1.9 I created hello world and then created a Index controller where i got list of all manufacturer. But how can I show this list in my theme layout like category or product listing.

Comment: do you want  manufacturer list in layered navigation ??

Comment: No i want to display in full page like site map or like list of category.

Answer (score 0):

Check this extension for free -

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ma2-manufacturers-free.html

Here is the demo for this extension -

> http://www.magenmarket.com/demo/extensions/index.php/ma2-manufacturers-free-module

You can follow this extension in order to know the Frontend and Backend module structure and custom template integration.

You can use the block codes given in **[Demo URL](http://www.magenmarket.com/demo/extensions/index.php/ma2-manufacturers-free-module)** in order to show the Manufacturer list on frontend.

Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks 
But i am not able to download this Module.At checkout page i am not move to froward after Billing Information.

Comment: You have to create an account on Magento Connect, then you will be able to download this extension. Create an account and try once again.